# Trying to figure out what happened with LightDM and Xorg

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, lightdm, bumblebee

Thank you for trying to help me with this issue! :)

I installed bumblebee and then my screen got a low resolution after my PC crashed (not related, cat pulled electric cable ;) ). To fix this issue I tried to uninstall Bumblebee, but no, now it gave me nothing but the login screen. The same applies if I try to uninstall the Nvidia driver.

I have tried a few things, such as

```
sudo chown $USER:$USER $HOME
rm ~./.Xauthority
```

I have also tried to uninstall and install bumblebee and nvidia numerous times on all of my kernels. But it seems like lightdm just do not want to be my friend any more...

Right now my graphics card is using the Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.6,256 bits) driver, and it is driving me nuts with this small screen.

Here is my [`Xorg.0.log`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/12967201/)

If you want any more logs, just tell me the command and I will paste it up on here for ya!

Thank you for helping me with this issue, I really appreciate it! :D

Answer (score 1):

So, I mainly just ran

```
sudo apt-get purge bumblebee
```

and voila, it was fixed.

Thank you everyone who helped me!