# Display became too big for the screen after installing an update for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: nvidia, 18.04, display, display-resolution

I am new to Linux and my laptop is asus gl552vw with two graphic cards, one of them is NVIDIA Gforce. I find both ASUS and NVIDIA have problem on Linux especially in terms of high resolution and all of the icons and screen were too small. So I used an additional Monitor with lower a resolution to work with. After a kernel update the Display became too big even the resolution shows correctly. I tried all the answers from these questions:

[Display became too big for the screen after upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/807972/display-became-too-big-for-the-screen-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-16-04)

[trying to figure out what happened with lightdm and Xorg](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689967/trying-to-figure-out-what-happened-with-lightdm-and-xorg/690103#690103)

[Ubuntu 18.04 Displays Issue -> Unknown Display](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1069451/ubuntu-18-04-displays-issue-unknown-display)

[Everything on the screen is suddenly Huge](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1060060)

But they didn't work for me.

Any help is really appreciated and please remember I am new to Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm newbie too..
But for me the solution was to install earlier version of nvidia.
After upgrade ubuntu from 16.04 to 18.04 I installed nvidia-352 (I used this instruction https://dev.to/bobnadler/ubuntu-1804-upgrade-problem-resolutions-1ni0).
And faced with 'too big display' problem.
So I used this command to know which versions of driver are in repository:

```
sudo apt-get update && clear && apt-cache search nvidia-[0-9] | grep 'binary driver'
```

I found nvidia-340.
So next I executed this set of command:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo apt-get install nvidia-340 nvidia-settings
sudo nvidia-xconfig
```

and rebooted system

Answer (score 1):

The answer by 'one more newbie' was helpful to me but didn't correct my situation.  What did work was to change the resolution from 1920x1080 (16:9) to 1680x1050 (16:10) in *Applications > Settings > Devices > Displays*.

For a listing of the nVidia card and drives use `ubuntu-drivers devices` to be certain of installing the correct driver.